# How can I get more results from anzograph

Tags: sparql, anzograph

I am using anzograph with SPARQL trough http using RDFlib. I do not specify any limits in my query, and still I only receive 1000 solutions. The same seems to happen on the web interface.
If I fire the same query on other triple stores with the same data, I do get all results.

Moreover, if I fire this query using their command line tool on the same machine as the database, I do get all results (millions). Maybe it is using a different protocol with the local database. If I specify the hostname and port explicitly on the command line, I get 1030 results...

Is there a way to specify that I want all results from anzograph over http?

I have found the `service_graph_rowset_limit` setting and changed its value to 100000000 in both `config/settings_standalone.conf` and `config/settings.conf`, (and restarted the database) but to no avail.

Comment: This question is all about AnzoGraph configuration and, even though you are using RDFlib, it's not really about RDFlib at all. Please could you remove the RDFlib tag? This will just prevent people from stumbling onto this issue for RDFlib info. Thanks!

Comment: I had waited a bit removing the tag because I wasn't sure what the actual cause was. Mainly because rdflib was behaving different from the command line. Now it appears rdflib had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

let me start by thanking you for pointing this issue out.
You have identified a regression of a fix, that had been intended to protect the web UI from freezing on unbounded result sets, but affected the regular sparql endpoint user as well.

Our Anzo customers do *not* see this issue, as they use the internal gRPC API directly.

We have produced a fix that will be in our upcoming anzograph 2.4.0 and in our upcoming patch release 2.3.2 set of images.
Older releases will receive this fix as well (when we have a shipment vehicle).

If it is urgent to you I can provide you both a point fix (root.war file).
What exact image are you using?

Best - Frank

Comment: We ended up with a workaround were we map the https port the command line tool is connecting to. Then, outside of the container we connect on that port while ignoring the certificates.

Comment: We are currently using Version 2.3.1 release 2021-03-31, there is no particular reason for that version. It is what came with the docker image.

Comment: yes that is the latest public release.
if you have a work around now, you do not need / seem to need a patch to address this issue. please ping me if that is the wrong assumption.

2.3.2 and some time after 2.4.0 will release soon both addressing the issue.

best - Frank

Comment: No need for now, indeed. I had communicated this and several other issues to Nick C. I would be happy to test  your next release.